# Does android 4.0.4 supports RTSP?

Tags: android, youtube, rtsp, android-videoview

Hi this might be a duplicate question but seems I can't find an answer, Im new to android and im using `RTSP` to get video url from youtube. I play the url i get using `videoview`, it works on my test device HTC sense (android 2.3.4) but it keeps on prompting me `"cannot play video"` in android 4.0.4? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You mean `android 4.0.4` is your device or emulator?

Comment: can you give me a code snippet on how to do this? my videoview just don't work on ICS. what does rtfm means?

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: Hi AamirKhan, I've seen that media-formats already. It says that it supports RTSP. And still clueless why its not playing in ICS.